# reverse using foldLeft in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
def foldLeft[A, B] (as: List[A], z: B) (f: (B, A) => B) : B = as match {
  case Nil => z
  case Cons(x, xs) => foldLeft(xs, f(z, x))(f)
}

def reverse[A] (as: List[A]): List[A] =
  foldLeft(as, List[A]())((h, acc) => Cons(acc, h))
```

I am not sure how List[A] in foldLeft is of type B. Can anyone clear the process happening in this functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reverse implementation is calling `foldLeft` with `A` as it's first type argument (`foldLeft#A = A`) and `List[A]` as it's second type argument (`foldLeft#B = List[A]`). Here is a type annotated version that makes this very explicit:

```
def reverse[A] (as: List[A]): List[A] =
  foldLeft[A, List[A]](as = as: List[A], z = List[A]())(
    (h: List[A], acc: A) => Cons(acc, h): List[A]
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Also `Cons` (if it is a `Cons` from standard library) creates a stream instead of list. Probably You want to use `::` instead:

```
def reverse[A] (as: List[A]): List[A] =
    foldLeft(as, List[A]())((acc, h) => h :: acc)
```